# Bluetooth adapter not initialized or unspecified address

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

How to solve *Bluetooth adapter not initialized or unspecified address*?

I am using the ble4.0 for getting the data from HMsoft device. I try my code on nexus 5, but it's not working for me.

Please help me to get proper data of accelerometer and gyroscope value from ble4.0.

```
 private void displayData(String data) {
     int v=0;
     series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
     if (data != null) {

         //if (isFloatPair(data)) {

         if (data.contains("\n"))
         {

             String[] point = data.split("\n");
             float x = Float.parseFloat(point[0]);

             if(x!=0){

                  v=(int) (x*0.001);
             Log.d("strIncom", data);
             Log.d("X: ",point[0]);

             }
             series.appendData(new DataPoint(10,v),true,10);

             series.setColor(Color.GREEN);
             graph.addSeries(series);
             graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
             graph.getViewport().setMinX(0);

         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Look at the Bluetooth LE [code samples](http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt/DeviceScanActivity.html) for examples how to get an working adapter.

Comment: i already tried this code its working but again n again scan with 2or more activities using ble4.0 not giving me proper output. It will stop the app.

Comment: Post your relevant code.

Comment: private void displayData(String data) {
      String temp = null,x=null,newstr,mystr;
      double value1 = 0;
         int lenx = 0;
       if (data != null) {
          x=new String(data);
        
                  value1 = Double.parseDouble(x);
                 }
                 
                  Log.d("Accel-X",String.valueOf(value1));
               if(value1!=0){
               
                int v=(int) (value1*0.001);
                line.addNewPoints(10,v);
                Log.d("line value",String.valueOf(v));
                view.repaint();
               }       }

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. You have to show how you try to get data from the device, edit your code in your post.